# Spark-Scala code runs to completion within Spark-Shell but runs infinitely via Spark-Submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a piece of Spark-Scala code that runs as expected in the Spark-Shell, but when launching via spark-submit (as shown below), executors continually fail with exit code 1 and the job runs infinitely.

```sh
./spark-submit --name Loader --class SP.Loader --master spark://spark-master.default.svc.cluster.local:7077 --executor-memory 64G --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.1 --conf spark.cores.max=280 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local --driver-memory 32G --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=16G /notebooks/Drago/scala/target/scala-2.11/loader_2.11-1.0.jar
```

```
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 11 requested
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 11
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 11 from BlockManagerMaster.
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20190910201611-0039/20 on hostPort 10.42.4.135:39575 with 35 core(s), 64.0 GB RAM
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190910201611-0039/20 is now RUNNING
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190910201611-0039/15 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20190910201611-0039/15 removed: Command exited with code 1
19/09/10 20:16:15 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20190910201611-0039/21 on worker-20190830191329-10.42.6.133-34823 (10.42.6.133:34823) with 35 core(s)
```

Comment: If your job is perpetually on accepted, it means your settings are too large for your cluster/executors and they will need to be reduced

Comment: If I reduce all settings to the default, I get the same behavior -- I can confirm that I have adequate resources as well

Comment: Go down these pathways (1) Submit inefficiently utilzes GC events compared to shell, check the DAG to see if it is going insane, if this is the problem I can toss some code below that I use; (2) in the DAG scheduler in what part of the code is your code running indefintely, if it is in the output of an IO operation persist the data set before the call; and (3) what is your data volume at, want to see if I can give you some submit confs that may help. Get back to me, I will try to help where I can.

Comment: @afeldman -- thanks ...I get the same behavior when I try to run the SparkPi example...don't know if this helps

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPi.scala